# How to use a linux command for set of files

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I'm looking for a solution to convert a set of files using the terminal and the command "convert" under linux. I can use "convert" for each file:

```
convert -quality 85 file.jpg file.jpg
```

But i'm looking for something like:

```
for each jpg do
  convert -quality 85 $file $file
end
```

Can someone tell me, which command i can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for i in *.jpg; do
   convert ... $i $i
done
```

should do it. That will work for sh/bash/zsh etc. It assumes that all your *.jpg files are in the current directory. Otherwise, replace *.jpg with an appropriate find invocation e.g.

```
for i in `find . -name "*.jpg" -print`; do
```

Note the backticks. These indicate that the enclosed command should be executed, and the results returned to the invoking structure (in this case, the for loop)

If you're using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org), then you can do

```
for i in **/*.jpg; do
```

to search subdirectories in your wildcard, and qualify these further using [advanced zsh wildcard syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6140012.html). I'm not sure what facilities bash offers in this area, however.

Comment: Don't forget xargs.  Not necessarily as powerful as a for loop, but often handy to know it's available:
    find -name '*.jpg' | xargs -l -i convert -quality 85 {} {}

Comment: ooh!  I didn't know you could do that with xargs!  I feel smarter.

Comment: or you can do it even without the xargs via: find . -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -quality 85 {} \:

Comment: Bash 4.0, once you enable the globstar shell option with `shopt -s globstar`, treats **/*.jpg just like Zsh does.

Comment: Instead of the backticks you can use $(...) which is IMHO a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `convert`ing each file by overwriting itself, you can use its sister command `mogrify`, that edits the file in place.  Also, both commands have built-in globbing, so they can modify all images in a single call, which is faster than running the program once per image.  See [*ImageMagick Command Line Processing*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) for more information.

So this will do:

```
mogrify '*.jpg' -quality 85
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Bash, you could do something like the following:

```
$ for f in `ls path/to/jpegs/*.jpg`; do convert -quality 85 $f $f; done
```

That will loop through all the JPEGs in a given directory and convert them.

If you're not using Bash, your shell may have a similar for-loop syntax; check the man pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a multicore machine, you can get some real speed by doing them in parallel:

```
mkdir -p converted
find -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 -P<number of cores> -n1 -Ifoo convert -quality 85 foo converted/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a shell script.  If your'e unfamiliar with shell programming, see [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html).

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg in `ls *.jpg`
do
    convert -quality 85 $arg $arg
done
```

Comment: '$files $files', not '$arg $arg'  or the other way around maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What about? :

```
find [-maxdepth 1] -iname "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -quality 85 {} \;
```

- optional `-maxdepth 1` to operate on current directory only (no subdir.)
- ImageMagick comes with `mogrify`, which modifies files in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec convert -quality 85 {} {} \;
```